# What are these different network connections in my PC settings?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

About half an hour earlier, my PC disconnected from the internet. I checked different network connections and found the image below:

[image]

I thought that the problem is with "Ethernet 5" as it said "Network Cable Unplugged". However, I tried different cables and it did not work.

Through, trial and error, I then diagnosed "Ethernet" and it said something about DHCP that fixed my network issue.

However, this made me curious about "Ethernet 4" and "Ethernet 5". Where did they come from?

Also, why does it say "Benjamin FrankLAN 2" below "Ethernet"?

Thanks.

Comment: The extra adapters are from your VPN setup

Comment: Thanks @John :)

So, Proton VPN created two different Ethernets? Where is the Benjamin FrankLAN 2 coming from?

Comment: It would appear to be related to some software you may have.